# When i try to update a table a date value is changing, but i dont want to

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have an SQL table. For example called "Fruits"

Columns: id, Name, Color, DateTime-Bought

When i try to edit (either manually or with a script) the Color of the fruit, **date is changing to current datetime**. How can i make the update script **and leave datetime as it was ?**

```
cURRENT SQL=
UPDATE `Fruits` SET `Color`='Red' WHERE `Name`='Apple'
```

I guess there are triggers involved and i use MariaDB.

i was guessing a simple solution something like READ first the current result of DateTime-Bought, make update and in the end overwrite again the previous value of DateTime-Bought :)

Comment: Show us the table definition. Are there any triggers involved?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What database system are you using (mysql, sql-server, etc..) ? Is there a trigger on this table ?

Comment: it is probably in the create table integrated and not done with triggers, so you need to alter the table

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a trigger defined, likely your column is defined as `TIMESTAMP` and not `DATETIME`.

By default MariaDB automatically assigns the following values for the first timestamp column:

- insert: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
- update: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

If you want to disable change of first timestamp column for UPDATE commands, define the TIMESTAMP with DEFAULT VALUE, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (a INT NOT NULL, b TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW());
```